# ActiveModel Serializer for complicated associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, active-model-serializers

I have 2 associated models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :notifications, foreign_key: :recipient_id
end

class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :recipient, class_name: 'User'
    belongs_to :actor, class_name: 'User'
    belongs_to :notifiable, polymorphic: true
end
```

I use a serializer for when I load a `:user`:

```
class API::UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :email, :auth_token, :location_id, :notifications

    has_many :notifications, foreign_key: :recipient_id, each_serializer: API::NotificationSerializer
end
```

which in turn uses a serializer for the `:notifications`:

```
class API::NotificationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :recipient_id, :actor_id, :notifiable_id, :read_at, :action, :recipient, :actor, :notifiable_type

    belongs_to :recipient, serializer: API::RecipientSerializer
    belongs_to :actor
    belongs_to :notifiable, polymorphic: true
end
```

However, **the `API::RecipientSerializer` is never used, and instead the whole `:recipient` is returned.  What am I doing wrong?**

---

Also, here is the `API::RecipientSerializer` for good measure:

```
class API::RecipientSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id
end
```

Comment: What happens if you change:

`has_many :notifications, foreign_key: :recipient_id, each_serializer: API::NotificationSerializer`

to

`has_many :notifications, foreign_key: :recipient_id, serializer: API::NotificationSerializer` ? Is the Notification serialized properly? (only the attributes serialized in the class?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. Check this [link](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/general/adapters.md#include-option). You need to set `ActiveModel::Serializer.config.default_includes = '**'` if you want your relationships to keep rendering recursively (or set it to whatever you need whenever serializing objects).
2. Don't add relations to `attributes` (remove `:recipient` from `attributes` in `NotificationSerializer`). This might work, as your relation will overwrite the attribute, but there's no reason to make them fight.

**EDIT**: As there seemed to be a problem with setting the `default_includes`, a specific one was needed while rendering the final result:

```
render json: user, include: ['notifications', 'notifications.recipient'], status: :ok
```

Comment: I was only able to get it working by using information from your link, specifically the `render json: user, include: ['notifications', 'notifications.recipient'], status: :ok`.  If you include this in your answer I can accept it

Comment: @JeremyThomas this is really weird though. Have you restarted your application after setting `ActiveModel::Serializer.config.default_includes`?

Comment: I am not sure then, it has always worked for me (similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52866002/rails-active-model-serializers-on-polymorphic-nested-association/52866844#52866844)). I'll add the specific includes in the answer.